# Is there any way to bind trait to class dinamically?

Tags: php, laravel, oop, traits

I have an array that has my traits:

```
$traits = [
  'app\traits\TraitNumOne',
  'app\traits\TraitNumTwo',
];
```

is there any way to use that traits in my class dinamically?

```
class MyClass {
use $traits[0],$traits[1]; // something like this :)
}
```

I haven't any idea to solve this, please help

Comment: AFAIK the only way is through `eval`. But if you have to use it there's definitely something wrong with your design.

Comment: Why do you need to do it? If you will explain what you want to do, maybe we can suggest another solution